# How to format values in an Echarts sunburst?

Tags: javascript, visualization, echarts

Given the following Echart sunburst visualization:

```
var data = [
  {
    name: 'Grandpa',
    value: 25000000,
    children: [
      {
        name: 'Uncle Leo',
        value: 15000000,
      },
      {
        name: 'Father',
        value: 10000000,
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    name: 'Nancy',
    value: 3000000,
    children: [
      {
        name: 'Cousin Betty',
        value: 1000000
      },
      {
        name: 'Cousin Jenny',
        value: 2000000
      }
    ]
  }
];
option = {
  tooltip: {
    trigger: 'item',
    formatter:  '{b}:<br/><b>{c}</b>',
  },
  series: {
    type: 'sunburst',
    // emphasis: {
    //     focus: 'ancestor'
    // },
    data: data,
    radius: [0, '90%'],
    label: {
      rotate: 'radial'
    }
  }
};
```

Hovering on `Grandpa` segment shows:

Grandpa:
**25000000000**

I would like to have a more readable value, like for example:

Grandpa:
**25 000 000 000**

I tried to solve this with `valueFormatter` but it doesn't seem to work on sunbursts.

Answer (score 0):

`valueFormatter` does work with sunburst. For `valueFormatter` to work properly,

1. It shouldn't be used along with `formatter`
2. EChart version should be at least 5.3.0

To separate thousands, this part:

```
  tooltip: {
    trigger: 'item',
    formatter:  '{b}:<br/><b>{c}</b>',
  },
```

Has to be replaced by:

```
  tooltip: {
    trigger: 'item',
    valueFormatter: value => value.toLocaleString(),
  },
```